# How do I resolve “Element bean is not allowed here” when configuring the XML file?

Tags: java, xml, spring, javabeans

I was creating a simple Java project by importing 4 major jar packages of Spring(beans, core, context and expression, all are ver 5.2.6). However, IDEA kept indicating that "element bean is not allowed here" even though I checked repeatedly that the dependencies are placed correctly in the module section and restarted the IDE. The configuration is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!--Creating User Object-->
    <bean id = "user" class = "com.zhouss.User"><bean/> #bean is where it reports error
</beans>
```

And here's a snapshot of the dependency jars:
[image: dependency jars configured]
[image: updated project info]

I'm a complete newbie on Spring, how do I resolve the issue?

Comment: Change to
<bean id = "user" class = "com.zhouss.User"></bean>

Comment: Tried that, still reported the same error. I am guessing it's still because the spring jar dependencies are somewhat not configured right, for there is no suggested messages prompted when typing "bean".

Comment: Show all your code. Do you use maven? Did you create class User?

Comment: Updated, the User class I created is left empty, and so are other classes.

Comment: No, did not use maven. Just created a java project.

Comment: I have no idea about your problem. XML-code looks like valid. But using simple java project without maven/gradle for Spring is a bad idea. Some packages needs another packages. For example spring-core needs spring-jcl,  spring-context needs spring-aop. Create maven project and add your dependencies in pom.xml file. Other dependencies will be added automatically.

Comment: I don't think it was caused by the lack of maven, as I have tried to start an identical maven project which still reports the same error, however, the project worked fine in eclipse, so I guess I will have to stick with Eclipse for now.

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out, it was a problem with the particular version of IDEA (2020.3, mac), I have updated to the latest version of 2022.1, mac and the error simply disappears by themselves.

I found very little info online when I tried to resolve this problem, so I find it necessary to write down my findings.